# Found more than 2 exes for binskim, panic! in MobSF

Tags: windows, mobile, nuget, security-framework

[See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYw5o.png)

This was happen when it was downloading and installing Binskim, Please help me.
Note: I'm trying to install MobSF.

```
E:\Pentest\Android\Tools\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\install\windows>python setup.py install
[*] Downloading config file..
[*] Saving to File config.txt
[*] Reading config file..
[*] Creating other folders...
[*] Checking dependencies...
[+] rsa is installed.
[+] Everything good.
[*] Downloading nuget..
[*] Saving to File nuget.exe
[*] Downloading and installing Binskim...
[!] Found more than 2 exes for binskim, panic!
```

Comment: Please, update the text and add info from the image inside the question

Comment: @Vasilisa I also wanna do that. But I don't have enough point to insert the image. I can only create link for image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and I made a print in setup.py to see the paths:
C:\Users\G\MobSF\Tools\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BinSkim.1.5.0-beta\tools\net461\win-x64\BinSkim.exe                                                                      C:\Users\G\MobSF\Tools\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BinSkim.1.5.0-beta\tools\net461\win-x64\BinSkim.exe.config                                                               C:\Users\G\MobSF\Tools\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BinSkim.1.5.0-beta\tools\net461\win-x86\BinSkim.exe                                                                      C:\Users\G\MobSF\Tools\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BinSkim.1.5.0-beta\tools\net461\win-x86\BinSkim.exe.config                                                               C:\Users\G\MobSF\Tools\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BinSkim.1.5.0-beta\tools\netcoreapp2.0\win-x64\BinSkim.exe                                                               C:\Users\G\MobSF\Tools\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BinSkim.1.5.0-beta\tools\netcoreapp2.0\win-x86\BinSkim.exe

I deleted C:\Users\G\MobSF\Tools\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BinSkim.1.5.0-beta\tools\net461 and it worked.